# Promise was created but not returned from. Knex / Bookshelf

Tags: node.js, promise, bookshelf.js, knex.js, passport.js

I'm getting a warning message in my console everytime I'm hitting a route that requires authentication.

(node:940) Warning: a promise was created in a handler at xxxxxx\app\config\passport.js:15:19 but was not returned from it, see http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/warning-explanations.html#warning-a-promise-was-created-in-a-handler-but-was-not-returned-from-it
    at .fetch (xxxxxx\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\method.js:13:13)

I've configured passport like this:

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const secret = process.env.SECRET;
var opts = {}

function passportConfig(db, passport) {
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
    opts.secretOrKey = secret;
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, payloadCallback.bind(null, db)));
}

function payloadCallback(db, payload, done) {
    new db.User({id: payload}).fetch()
    .then(response => response.toJSON())
    .then(user => done(null, user))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

module.exports = passportConfig;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `payloadCallback` doesn't return anything

Comment: @JaromandaX I thought that when i use .then(user => done(null, user)) that would be the same as saying .then(function(user) { return done(null, user)}). I tested it just to be sure and I still get the same warning. Even if I use "return new db.User....."

Comment: where is the `.fetch()` function from?

Comment: @JaromandaX it comes from bookshelf.js http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-fetch

Comment: odd ... fetch returns a Promise, all your then/catch return values - not sure what bluebird is whining about! Have you included bluebird or did one of the other libraries?

Comment: @JaromandaX BookshelfJS includes Bluebird. The way I fixed it was to replace the last then and catch with a .asPromise(done).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this warning by replacing the second then and catch with .asCallback(done).

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const secret = process.env.SECRET;
var opts = {}

function passportConfig(db, passport) {
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
    opts.secretOrKey = secret;
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, payloadCallback.bind(null, db)));
}

function payloadCallback(db, payload, done) {
    new db.User({id: payload}).fetch()
    .then(response => response.toJSON())
    .asCallback(done);
}

module.exports = passportConfig;
```

Comment: This solved the issue for me, as well. Thanks so much! This was a really strange one.